# OpenFileInput() - Where to put raw files? (.txt)

Tags: android, android-file, android-context

I have something like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("database_values.txt");
```

I found so many different threads about "how to read a txt-file?" and similar stuff, but I never saw, where people placed this file? There should be some folder in the "res" section, that should handle files like this, or am I false?

Where do I have to put this file, that it will be found by on runtime?

Comment: The assets folder is a common place to store text files.

Comment: In intellij idea you can mark a directory as "resources" and during build the files in the folder will be copied in the output directory

Comment: @MarcoAcierno: I've uploaded a screenshot (http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/big/1fby-6v-f340.png). I created a folder like Marco said, but I'm absolutely unsure about the "Resource Type". + I wasn't able to see an assets folder? Anyway, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: create a new directory named "assets" and you are ok